# Smooth Scroll panel in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hiii all,

I am working on an android project and i have to make a smooth scrolling panel like shown in this app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paisaswipe.android

I tried this with the help of panels, but when i tested it on a real android device then app goes crashed. And that layout is also not looks good and completely aligned.

So, can anyone suggest me that how i can implement this thing in android???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout
https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport

Example on Google Play:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sebastianopoggi.samples.ui.GlowPadSample

Comment: Hey Ali,
actually i want to make a lock screen that is basically we have on our android phones.
Like i want to perform some actions on left and right swipes. 
But, how can i make that swipe smooth and how i can design that type of lock screen????

Comment: Can you give me more links of this type of example that can be run on older devices also????

Comment: From the project github page "A backport of the Android 4.2 GlowPadView that works on the SDK on API levels 4+." which means it runs on Android 1.6 and newer versions.